# How can I reduce the spacing between these columns/ images using bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, padding, bootstrap-4, margins, grid-system

I can't figure our how to make the images closer together. It seems the extra green space is coming from the column width.

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="img/thumbnail1.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="img/thumbnail2.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="img/thumbnail3.png">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img  src="img/thumbnail4.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="img/thumbnail5.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="img/thumbnail6.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: This is what it looks like.]

[image: This is what it should look like.]

Answer (score 0):

Just Apply this CSS in your Code

```
.col-md-4 img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

I think this is you want. It helps you Have a Nice Day.

Comment: Thanks, but that only made the images huge.